# Springs Properties

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

I want to ask for a knowledge (preferably online) source about springs properties.

I would like to know how **Logarithmic decrement** relates to **type of material** and **spring shape (type)** and how to minimize it effectively.

Purpose is to build pendulum using spring and mass which can 'bounce' permanently with as little force (to balance dissipation of energy) as possible.

Thank You in advance for any help